# Django url pathing, home url always overwriting path('', views.home, name='home')

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),  
    path('', views.home, name='home'),

]
```

this is my code for the URLs under my something I call timetable

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signup/' , include('timetable.urls')),
    path('', include('timetable.urls')),
]
```

this is the code for the main urls.py

so I know that the call to the other url.py works as if I take the '' (home) URL out it redirects  to the right URL (the view that I have in place) but if I have the home URL in it just always goes straight to that URL, is there any way like in react where I can do Exact or do you guys know of any solution for this that is simple

Comment: What are the actual url's that aren't directing you to the correct view and what views should they be redirect to? Alternatively install `django-extensions` and use the `show_urls` command.

Comment: you are adding signup/ two times in fact. It is equal to remove it either from urls in root directory or the one in application, and it wll work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way it's configured, `127.0.0.1:8000/` and `127.0.0.1:8000/signup/` will go to `views.home` and `127.0.0.1:8000/signup/signup/` will go to `views.signup`. Remove the `'signup/'` path from your main urls.py file and it should work as expected.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('timetable.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Thanks, mate for taking your time to help me! it was just that!